# Firebase conflicts my gradle *Mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes"

Tags: android, firebase

At least I believe firebase is the problem since it only happens when I add admob to the the mix

if I dont add this line     `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'` everything is ok. trying to find a way to find older versions of this library to maybe resolve my error but to no luck

```
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
```

[image]

Comment: are you getting warning or error ?

Comment: Do you get an error or what is the behaviour? Please also share the content of the other build.gradle file. Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Hello, I have added the Error as screenshot on my original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those warnings can be solved by adding the following lines of code in your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Ok this seemed to do the trick>
but I get this on my console add a valid  *
    * App ID inside the AndroidManifest
I just need to do my manifest and add my id when i get one and it be ok right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1'`

Comment: Hi i added the error as screenshot on my original post